# Full text search with php

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I do not get any results for the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST('hello' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

while test2 looks like:

```
id | txt
 1 | ...
 2 | ...
 3 | ...
 4 | ...
.. | ...
```

txt is 30 characters long (TEXT) and fulltext. I have about 16 records (tiny db) and the word hello is placed almost in every record in txt along with other words. I just wanted to know how full-text search works. So i get zero results and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two reasons that you are not getting any results:

Reason 1: your search word 'hello' occurs in too many rows.

> A natural language search interprets
>   the search string as a phrase in
>   natural human language (a phrase in
>   free text). There are no special
>   operators. The stopword list applies.
>   In addition, words that are present in
>   50% or more of the rows are considered
>   common and do not match. Full-text
>   searches are natural language searches
>   if no modifier is given.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Reason 2: your search word 'hello' is on the stop-word list.
Any word on the stopword list will never match!

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html